# How do I view html from a website in a View (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to show the html from this site in a text field in swift. I have been able to parse some html in UIKit App Delegate/Storyboard, however I don't know how to do it in the new SwiftUI App/SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("swag")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

I have tried to put the following code below the `struct ContentView: View {` and above `var body: some View {` :

```
let url = URL(string: "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=1&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=1&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=39.743&longitude=-105.178&timezone=-7.0&elev=1829&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {
        print("data was nil")
        return
    }
    
    guard let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        print("cannot cast data into string")
        return
    }
    print(htmlString)
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: That's not HTML, that's plain text in CSV format. Split the text in paragraphs and then split the paragraphs by comma. Is there no JSON output which is easier to parse?

Comment: @Asperi I don't want to display the website in a view, I want to get the actual html. In this case I want to get the sun angle for every hour of the day and then create a graph with them!

Comment: I think for Swift UI you should use a totally different approach. Googling I found this aritcle for swiftUI https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui